# Check NSString Contains Both Letters And Numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm looking for the best way to check that an NSString contains both numerical and alphabetical characters. 
What I have come up with so far is the code below but this just tells me that no characters were entered which aren't numbers or letters.

```
if( [[myNSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
            [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]){    
  //The string only contains alpha or numerical characters.
  //But now I want to check that both character sets are present ?    
}
```

Comment: I know that it's heresy to say this but the simplest, most understandable, and most efficient way to do this is almost certainly to just loop through the string, extract each character with `characterAtIndex`, and test it against the appropriate bounds.  With the others you'd better have some pretty darn good comments if you want to understand the code 6 months from now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just trim letterCharacterSet and decimalDigitCharacterSet and check if produced string is not equal to the original string:

```
if (![[myOriginalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:myOriginalString] 
     && ![[myOriginalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:myOriginalString]) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. Yes this is what I ended up doing in the end.

Comment: detect a bug: if the string contains control character , it returns YES, that's wrong.

Answer (score 6):

kovpas' answer works fine if you have letters at the beginning or end and digits on the opposite end.  A problem occurs if digits are embedded between letters or vice-versa, such as 'abc123abc'.  Here is a solution:

```
if (![[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""] isEqualToString:str]  
    && ![[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""] isEqualToString:str]) {  
    ....  
}
```

Comment: this answer works much better! I am not sure why you are using `invertedSet` though. Thanks

Comment: The trick to this problem is that it is more complicated to check for an affirmation.  The first check builds a string without digits; if the string is identical to the original, then there are no digits in the string.  A similar check is done with the second check for letters.  This is why there are NOT's for the 2 conditions.

Comment: yes, but you don't need to use `invertedSet`, it works perfectly even without it

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure the two previous answers cover the requirements, so this is an answer corresponding to a stricter interpretation of the requirements.

Taking the requirements from the comments in the code of the original post:

```
//The string only contains alpha or numerical characters.   
//But now I want to check that both character sets are present?
```

This means that a string to pass the test must consist of only numbers and letters and at least one of each.

`NSString`'s `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` finds a character in a string if it belongs to a certain set, so we can use that one.

```
NSString *string = // ... string to test;

NSCharacterSet *illegalChars = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];

// Test if there is an illegal character in the string
BOOL hasIllegalCharacter = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: illegalCharacterSet].location != NSNotFound;

BOOL hasLetter = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound;

BOOL hasDigit  = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound;

if (hasDigit  && hasLetter  && !hasIllegalCharacter  ) {
    // String OK
}
```

As detailed in the docs, the `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` returns an NSRange of {NSNotFound, 0} in case no character from the set is found in the string. This is similar to other methods to search for strings or characters in a string in Cocoa.